# Use tokens in PHP filter

Tags: tokens

i want make a photo gallery with drupal and i need to:

1. a download button for current node picture
2. an embed code that allow visitor to use photo on other Websites. like this:
   [image]

i have some experience with Drupal and reading PHP codes, but no experience with writing PHP codes. i tried to make a block in bottom of node picture with PHP filter and following content:

```
<pre><a href="<?php t('[node:url]'); ?>" title="<?php t('[node:title]'); ?>"><img src="<?php t('[node:field_image]'); ?>"></a></pre>
```

this code not work. please help me.

many thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To translate the tokens in their values, you can use:

[`token_replace`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!token.inc/function/token_replace/7)

e.g:

```
$nid = token_replace('[node:nid]', array('node' => $node));
```

You need to be able to pass the required parameters for that token, e.g `$node` for node tokens.

Comment: using:
<?php
$nid = token_replace('[node:nid]', array('node' => $node));
echo $nid;
?>
gives error:
Notice: Undefined variable: node in eval() (line 2 of /srv/http/g/modules/php/php.module(80) : eval()'d code).

Comment: As mentioned, you'll need to get the `$node` object first. That depends on the code context. Sometimes, if on a node page, it's `$node = menu_get_object('node');`

Comment: as i said i have not experience to write PHP codes, and thanks to show me the way directly. i used this and worked: <a href="<?php $node = menu_get_object('node'); $url = token_replace('[node:url]', array('node' => $node)); echo $url; ?>" title="<?php $node = menu_get_object('node'); $title = token_replace('[node:title]', array('node' => $node)); echo $title; ?>"><img src="<?php $node = menu_get_object('node'); $field_image = token_replace('[node:field_image]', array('node' => $node)); echo $field_image; ?>"></a>
thanks man :)